# Knowledge Catalogue

Tags: java, swing, gui

All that the program does is query a database that I have setup, when the user selects the returned fields, which are populated based on the selection of the field above it.

[image: Application]

The application is basically 3 classes:

1. `DbConnect`: Generates queries that are sent to the database

   2. `Nested` - `QueryFields`: Contains all user-selected fields to generate queries
2. `Main` (probably needs a name change): Contains all information for initializing the GUI

I would like to optimize my main class and separate concerns more efficiently.

**Main Class**

```
public class Main {
/**
 * Launch the application.
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Display display = Display.getDefault();
    // Allow the application to run as threaded
    Realm.runWithDefault(SWTObservables.getRealm(display), new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Main window = new Main();
                window.open();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

protected Shell    shlPstmKnowledgeCatalogue;
protected Shell    contactDialog;
protected Shell    helpDialog;
private Combo      applicationCombo;
private Button     btnQuickParts;
private Button     btnCopyToClipboard;
private Combo      categoryCombo;
private Combo      combo_1;
private Combo      subcatCombo;
private List       issueList;
private FormData   fd_applicationCombo;
private FormData   fd_btnQuickParts;
private FormData   fd_issues_1;
private FormData   fd_list;
private FormData   fd_script;
private FormData   fd_text;
private DbConnect  conn;
private StyledText script;
private StyledText workInstructions;
private Label      lblTool;
private Label      lblWorkInstructions;
private Hyperlink  hprlnkDocumentAvailable;
private final FormToolkit formToolkit = new FormToolkit(Display.getDefault());
private String    contactDev = "For specific questions, suggestions, or if you would like to submit content for use in the tool, please contact me for assistance:"
                          + "\n\nEmail: <email>"
                          + "\nSubject: Knowledge Catalogue";
private String    quickParts = "Status Pending - Client Action Required (Add Info)\n\nUser,\n " + 

                            "\nIn order to further troubleshoot the issue, please provide the following:\n\n" + 

                            "1. The steps to reproduce the issue or the error message – What did you do before the error happened or what steps to take to get the error again?\n\n" +

                            "2. Expected results – What should have happened when you followed your steps?\n\n" + 

                            "3. Actual Results – What actually happened when you did these steps?\n\n" + 

                            "4. Screen shot of the error message or issue – Attach a screen shot of what you see following the above steps (error message, outcome, etc.).\n\n" + 

                            "5. What browser and version are you using to log into SiteHandler while experiencing this issue?\n\n" + 

                            "Please reply back to this email within 2 days with the requested information so it can be added to this ticket. If no reply, this ticket will automatically resolve in 3 business days.\n\n" +

                            "Thanks,\n\n";

/**
 * Create an instance of the Combo object to contain all categories
 * for a selected application. The combo box will not be populated
 * until the user has selected an application.
 */
private FormData createCategoryCombo() {
    /* Create specific problem list after tool selected */
    ComboViewer comboViewer = new ComboViewer(shlPstmKnowledgeCatalogue, SWT.READ_ONLY);
    categoryCombo = comboViewer.getCombo();
    categoryCombo.setCursor(SWTResourceManager.getCursor(SWT.CURSOR_HAND));
    categoryCombo.setDragDetect(false);
    categoryCombo.setFont(SWTResourceManager.getFont("Calibri", 11, SWT.NORMAL));
    categoryCombo.setToolTipText("The general problem-scope that the ticket falls under.");

    fd_list = new FormData();
    fd_list.left = new FormAttachment(applicationCombo, 0, SWT.LEFT);
    categoryCombo.setLayoutData(fd_list);
    formToolkit.adapt(categoryCombo, true, true);

    return fd_list;
}

/**
 * Creates the Button instance to be used for the Copy to Clipboard functionality
 * This copies the contents of the Script text box to the Clipboard.
 */
private void createCopyBtn(FormData fd_btnQuickParts, final Display display) {
    /* Create button to copy generated message to the Clipboard */
    btnCopyToClipboard = new Button(shlPstmKnowledgeCatalogue, SWT.NONE);
    btnCopyToClipboard.setFont(SWTResourceManager.getFont("Calibri", 10, SWT.BOLD));
    btnCopyToClipboard.setDragDetect(false);
    btnCopyToClipboard.setCursor(SWTResourceManager.getCursor(SWT.CURSOR_HAND));
    btnCopyToClipboard.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
        }
    });
    btnCopyToClipboard.setToolTipText("Copy the contents of the Script text box to the clipboard.");

    FormData fd_btnCopyToClipboard = new FormData();
    fd_btnCopyToClipboard.top = new FormAttachment(script, 6);
    fd_btnCopyToClipboard.right = new FormAttachment(script, 0, SWT.RIGHT);
    btnCopyToClipboard.setLayoutData(fd_btnCopyToClipboard);
    formToolkit.adapt(btnCopyToClipboard, true, true);
    btnCopyToClipboard.setText("Copy to Clipboard");

    {
    /* Create listener for Copy button */
    btnCopyToClipboard.addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener() {
          public void handleEvent(Event event) {
            Clipboard clipboard = new Clipboard(display);
            String plainText    = script.getText();
            String rtfText      = "{\\rtf1\\b " + script.getText() + "}";
            TextTransfer textTransfer = TextTransfer.getInstance();
            RTFTransfer rftTransfer   = RTFTransfer.getInstance();
            clipboard.setContents(new String[]{plainText, rtfText}, new Transfer[]{textTransfer, rftTransfer});
            clipboard.dispose();
          }
        });
    }
}

/**
 * Creates an instance of the Combo object to contain all issues.
 * For issues to be populated, an appropriate Application, and Category
 * must be selected by the user.
 */
private FormData createsubcatCombo() {
    ComboViewer comboViewer = new ComboViewer(shlPstmKnowledgeCatalogue, SWT.READ_ONLY);
    subcatCombo = comboViewer.getCombo();
    subcatCombo.setBackgroundImage(null);
    subcatCombo.setCursor(SWTResourceManager.getCursor(SWT.CURSOR_HAND));
    subcatCombo.setBackground(SWTResourceManager.getColor(SWT.COLOR_WIDGET_LIGHT_SHADOW));
    subcatCombo.setDragDetect(false);
    subcatCombo.setFont(SWTResourceManager.getFont("Calibri", 11, SWT.NORMAL));
    subcatCombo.setToolTipText("Narrow down the general category to a more specific problem scope");
    subcatCombo.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
            conn.getFields().setSubCategory(subcatCombo.getItem(subcatCombo.getSelectionIndex()));
            ArrayList<String> list = conn.listQuery("issue");
            issueList.removeAll();
            script.setText(" ");
            workInstructions.setText(" ");
            hprlnkDocumentAvailable.setHref("");
            hprlnkDocumentAvailable.setVisible(false);
            for (String str : list) {
                issueList.add(str);
            }
        }
    });

    fd_issues_1 = new FormData();
    fd_issues_1.right = new FormAttachment(applicationCombo, 0, SWT.RIGHT);
    fd_issues_1.left = new FormAttachment(applicationCombo, 0, SWT.LEFT);
    subcatCombo.setLayoutData(fd_issues_1);
    formToolkit.adapt(subcatCombo, true, true);

    return fd_issues_1;
}

/**
 * Populates all labels for the application with their appropriate text,
 * position, and FormData
 */
private void createLabels(FormData fd_toolCombo, FormData fd_category, FormData fd_issues, FormData fd_script) {
    /* Create label for tool combobox */
    lblTool  = formToolkit.createLabel(shlPstmKnowledgeCatalogue, "Application", SWT.BORDER | SWT.SHADOW_IN);
    lblTool.setBackgroundImage(null);
    lblTool.setForeground(SWTResourceManager.getColor(SWT.COLOR_WHITE));
    lblTool.setFont(SWTResourceManager.getFont("Calibri", 9, SWT.NORMAL));
    lblTool.setBackground(SWTResourceManager.getColor(SWT.COLOR_WIDGET_DARK_SHADOW));
    FormData fd_lblTool = new FormData();
    fd_lblTool.left = new FormAttachment(applicationCombo, 0, SWT.LEFT);
    lblTool.setLayoutData(fd_lblTool);

    /* Create label for category combobox */
    Label lblProblem = formToolkit.createLabel(shlPstmKnowledgeCatalogue, "Category", SWT.BORDER);
    fd_list.top = new FormAttachment(lblProblem, 6);
    lblProblem.setForeground(SWTResourceManager.getColor(SWT.COLOR_WHITE));
    lblProblem.setBackground(SWTResourceManager.getColor(SWT.COLOR_WIDGET_DARK_SHADOW));
    lblProblem.setFont(SWTResourceManager.getFont("Calibri", 9, SWT.NORMAL));
    FormData fd_lblProblem = new FormData();
    fd_lblProblem.left = new FormAttachment(applicationCombo, 0, SWT.LEFT);
    fd_lblProblem.top = new FormAttachment(applicationCombo, 6);
    lblProblem.setLayoutData(fd_lblProblem);

    /* Create the label for the Issue list */
    Label lblIssue = formToolkit.createLabel(shlPstmKnowledgeCatalogue, "Sub-Category", SWT.BORDER);
    fd_issues_1.top = new FormAttachment(lblIssue, 6);
    lblIssue.setForeground(SWTResourceManager.getColor(SWT.COLOR_WHITE));
    lblIssue.setBackground(SWTResourceManager.getColor(SWT.COLOR_WIDGET_DARK_SHADOW));
    lblIssue.setFont(SWTResourceManager.getFont("Calibri", 9, SWT.NORMAL));
    FormData fd_lblIssue = new FormData();
    fd_lblIssue.left = new FormAttachment(applicationCombo, 0, SWT.LEFT);
    fd_lblIssue.top = new FormAttachment(categoryCombo, 6);
    lblIssue.setLayoutData(fd_lblIssue);

    /* Create the label for the Script text bow */
    Label lblScript = formToolkit.createLabel(shlPstmKnowledgeCatalogue, "Script", SWT.BORDER);
    fd_text.bottom = new FormAttachment(lblScript, -6);
    fd_script.top = new FormAttachment(lblScript, 6);
    lblScript.setFont(SWTResourceManager.getFont("Calibri", 9, SWT.NORMAL));
    lblScript.setForeground(SWTResourceManager.getColor(SWT.COLOR_WHITE));
    lblScript.setBackground(SWTResourceManager.getColor(SWT.COLOR_WIDGET_DARK_SHADOW));
    FormData fd_lblScript = new FormData();
    fd_lblScript.left = new FormAttachment(0, 196);
    fd_lblScript.top = new FormAttachment(0, 158);
    lblScript.setLayoutData(fd_lblScript);

    /* Create the label for the Work Instructions text box */
    lblWorkInstructions = formToolkit.createLabel(shlPstmKnowledgeCatalogue, "Work Instructions", SWT.BORDER);
    fd_lblTool.top = new FormAttachment(lblWorkInstructions, 0, SWT.TOP);
    fd_text.top = new FormAttachment(lblWorkInstructions, 7);
    lblWorkInstructions.setFont(SWTResourceManager.getFont("Calibri", 9, SWT.NORMAL));
    lblWorkInstructions.setForeground(SWTResourceManager.getColor(SWT.COLOR_WHITE));
    lblWorkInstructions.setBackground(SWTResourceManager.getColor(SWT.COLOR_WIDGET_DARK_SHADOW));
    FormData fd_lblWorkInstructions = new FormData();
    fd_lblWorkInstructions.top = new FormAttachment(0, 9);
    fd_lblWorkInstructions.left = new FormAttachment(0, 196);
    lblWorkInstructions.setLayoutData(fd_lblWorkInstructions);
}

/**
 * Creates the listeners for the Application, Category, and Issues
 * combo boxes.
 */
private void createListeners() {
    /* Add SelectionListener to toolCombo box */
    applicationCombo.addSelectionListener(new SelectionListener() {
          public void widgetDefaultSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
          }

          public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {

              /* Create SelectionListener for category combo box */
                categoryCombo.addSelectionListener(new SelectionListener() {
                    public void widgetDefaultSelected(SelectionEvent arg0) {
                    }

                    public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent arg0) {
                        conn.getFields().setCategory(categoryCombo.getItem(categoryCombo.getSelectionIndex()));
                        ArrayList<String> list = conn.listQuery("sub_category");
                        subcatCombo.removeAll();
                        issueList.removeAll();
                        script.setText(" ");
                        workInstructions.setText(" ");
                        hprlnkDocumentAvailable.setHref("");
                        hprlnkDocumentAvailable.setVisible(false);
                        /* Add all of the issues for the category, to the issue combo box */
                        for (String str : list) {
                            subcatCombo.add(str);
                        }
                    }
                });
           /* Add all categories available, for the tool selected */
            conn.getFields().setTool(applicationCombo.getItem(applicationCombo.getSelectionIndex()));
            subcatCombo.removeAll();
            issueList.removeAll();
            hprlnkDocumentAvailable.setHref("");
            hprlnkDocumentAvailable.setVisible(false);
            populatecategoryCombo();
          }
    });
}


/**
 * Creates the menu drop-down bar and populates is with all of the available
 * options.
 */
private void createMenuBar() {
    /* Create the main menu bar */
    Menu menu = new Menu(shlPstmKnowledgeCatalogue, SWT.BAR);
    shlPstmKnowledgeCatalogue.setMenuBar(menu);

    MenuItem mntmNewSubmenu = new MenuItem(menu, SWT.CASCADE);
    mntmNewSubmenu.setText("Menu");

    Menu menu_1 = new Menu(mntmNewSubmenu);
    mntmNewSubmenu.setMenu(menu_1);

    MenuItem mntmHelp = new MenuItem(menu_1, SWT.NONE);
    mntmHelp.setText("Help");

    // Display the help dialog box when the "Help" menu item has been selected
    mntmHelp.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
            helpDialog = new Shell(shlPstmKnowledgeCatalogue, SWT.APPLICATION_MODAL | SWT.DIALOG_TRIM);
            helpDialog.setText("Help");

            // Create the possible options for help
            Menu helpMenu = new Menu(helpDialog, SWT.BAR);
            MenuItem howToMenuItem = new MenuItem(helpMenu, SWT.BUTTON1);
            MenuItem errorsMenuItem = new MenuItem(helpMenu, SWT.BUTTON1);
            final StyledText text = new StyledText(helpDialog,  SWT.WRAP | SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.CANCEL | SWT.READ_ONLY);
            text.setFont(SWTResourceManager.getFont("Calibri", 12, SWT.NORMAL));
            helpDialog.setMenuBar(helpMenu);
            errorsMenuItem.setText("Errors");
            errorsMenuItem.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
                public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
                    text.setText(conn.helpQuery("Errors"));
                }
            });

            howToMenuItem.setText("How-To");
            howToMenuItem.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
                public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
                    text.setText(conn.helpQuery("How To"));
                }
            });

            text.setSize(665, 345);
            text.setText("Select a help topic from the menu to generate the specific help dialog.");
            text.setVisible(true);
            helpDialog.setLocation(shlPstmKnowledgeCatalogue.getBounds().x, shlPstmKnowledgeCatalogue.getBounds().y);
            helpDialog.setSize(671, 396);
            helpDialog.open();
        }
    });

    MenuItem mntmContactDeveloper = new MenuItem(menu_1, SWT.NONE);
    mntmContactDeveloper.setText("Contact Developer");

    // Display the contact developer dialog box when the "Contact Developer" menu item has been selected
    mntmContactDeveloper.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
                    contactDialog = new Shell(shlPstmKnowledgeCatalogue, SWT.APPLICATION_MODAL | SWT.DIALOG_TRIM);
                    contactDialog.setText("Contact Developer");
                    StyledText text = new StyledText(contactDialog, SWT.BORDER | SWT.WRAP | SWT.CANCEL | SWT.READ_ONLY);

                    // Bold email address
                    StyleRange emailStyle = new StyleRange();
                    emailStyle.start = contactDev.indexOf("evan");
                    emailStyle.length = 25;
                    emailStyle.fontStyle = SWT.BOLD;

                    // Bold subject line
                    StyleRange subjectStyle = new StyleRange();
                    subjectStyle.start = contactDev.indexOf("Subject:") + 9;
                    subjectStyle.length = 19;
                    subjectStyle.fontStyle = SWT.BOLD;

                    text.setSize(295, 150);
                    text.setText(contactDev);
                    text.setStyleRange(emailStyle);
                    text.setStyleRange(subjectStyle);
                    text.setVisible(true);

                    contactDialog.setLocation(shlPstmKnowledgeCatalogue.getBounds().x, shlPstmKnowledgeCatalogue.getBounds().y);
                    contactDialog.setSize(300, 150);
                    contactDialog.open();
                }
            });
}

/**
 * Create a Button instance to be used to populate the script text box
 * with the commonly used, four-question quick part.
 */
private FormData createQuickPartsBtn(FormData fd_toolCombo) {

    TextViewer textViewer = new TextViewer(shlPstmKnowledgeCatalogue, SWT.BORDER | SWT.WRAP | SWT.V_SCROLL);
    workInstructions  = textViewer.getTextWidget();
    workInstructions.setBackground(SWTResourceManager.getColor(SWT.COLOR_LIST_BACKGROUND));
    fd_list.right = new FormAttachment(workInstructions, -6);

    fd_applicationCombo.right = new FormAttachment(workInstructions, -6);
    fd_script.right = new FormAttachment(workInstructions, 0, SWT.RIGHT);
    fd_script.left = new FormAttachment(workInstructions, 0, SWT.LEFT);
    fd_applicationCombo.top = new FormAttachment(0, 34);

    workInstructions.setEditable(false);
    workInstructions.setFont(SWTResourceManager.getFont("Calibri", 11, SWT.NORMAL));
    workInstructions.setToolTipText("Displays the work instructions for a given application, category, and issue.");

    fd_text = new FormData();
    fd_text.left = new FormAttachment(0, 194);
    fd_text.right = new FormAttachment(100, -6);
    workInstructions.setLayoutData(fd_text);
    formToolkit.adapt(workInstructions, true, true);

    /* Set detailed button settings */
    btnQuickParts = new Button(shlPstmKnowledgeCatalogue, SWT.FLAT);
    btnQuickParts.setFont(SWTResourceManager.getFont("Calibri", 10, SWT.BOLD));
    btnQuickParts.setBackground(SWTResourceManager.getColor(SWT.COLOR_WIDGET_DARK_SHADOW));
    btnQuickParts.setLocation(new Point(500, 360));
    btnQuickParts.setDragDetect(false);
    btnQuickParts.setCursor(SWTResourceManager.getCursor(SWT.CURSOR_HAND));
    btnQuickParts.setText("Bug Fix Questions");
    btnQuickParts.setToolTipText("Generate quick part to get more information from the user.");
    btnQuickParts.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
            script.setText(quickParts);
            hprlnkDocumentAvailable.setVisible(false);
            workInstructions.setText(" ");
            if (quickParts.contains("User")) {
                int startIndex = quickParts.indexOf("User,", 0);
                script.setSelection(startIndex, startIndex + 4);
                script.showSelection();
                script.forceFocus();
            }
        }
    });
    fd_script.bottom = new FormAttachment(btnQuickParts, -6);
    fd_btnQuickParts = new FormData();
    fd_btnQuickParts.left = new FormAttachment(workInstructions, 0, SWT.LEFT);
    fd_btnQuickParts.bottom = new FormAttachment(100, -10);
    btnQuickParts.setLayoutData(fd_btnQuickParts);
    formToolkit.adapt(btnQuickParts, true, true);

    return fd_btnQuickParts;
}

/**
 * Create a text box to be used in displaying the script, upon selecting
 * an appropriate issue. The contents of this text box are read-only and
 * can be copied to the clipboard using the button below the box.
 */
private FormData createScriptBox() {
    /* Create script textbox, after selecting tool */
    TextViewer textViewer = new TextViewer(shlPstmKnowledgeCatalogue, SWT.BORDER | SWT.WRAP | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.CANCEL);
    script = textViewer.getTextWidget();
    script.setBackground(SWTResourceManager.getColor(SWT.COLOR_WHITE));
    script.setBackgroundImage(null);
    script.setToolTipText("Displays the generated script for a given application, tool, and issue.");
    script.setFont(SWTResourceManager.getFont("Calibri", 11, SWT.NORMAL));
    script.setVisible(true);

    fd_script = new FormData();
    script.setLayoutData(fd_script);
    formToolkit.adapt(script, true, true);

    return fd_script;
}


/**
 * Creates the shell and sets the appropriate parameters for displaying
 * the application.
 */
private void createShell(Display display) throws IOException {
    shlPstmKnowledgeCatalogue = new Shell(display);
    shlPstmKnowledgeCatalogue.setFont(SWTResourceManager.getFont("Calibri", 9, SWT.NORMAL));
    shlPstmKnowledgeCatalogue.setImage(SWTResourceManager.getImage(Main.class, "/images/icon.png"));
    shlPstmKnowledgeCatalogue.setBackgroundImage(SWTResourceManager.getImage(Main.class, "/images/bg2.png"));
    shlPstmKnowledgeCatalogue.setSize(671, 396);
    shlPstmKnowledgeCatalogue.setLocation(550, 350);
    shlPstmKnowledgeCatalogue.setMinimumSize(671, 396);
    shlPstmKnowledgeCatalogue.setText("Knowledge Catalogue v1.2");
    shlPstmKnowledgeCatalogue.setLayout(new FormLayout());
}

/**
 * Creates an instance of the Combo object to contain all Applications.
 * This combo is populated once the application is opened.
 */
private FormData createApplicationCombo() {
    /* Create and populate the toolCombo box */
    ComboViewer comboViewer = new ComboViewer(shlPstmKnowledgeCatalogue, SWT.READ_ONLY);
    applicationCombo = comboViewer.getCombo();
    applicationCombo.setToolTipText("Environment that the ticket or problem relates to");
    applicationCombo.setFont(SWTResourceManager.getFont("Calibri", 11, SWT.NORMAL));
    applicationCombo.setCursor(SWTResourceManager.getCursor(SWT.CURSOR_HAND));
    applicationCombo.setDragDetect(false);

    fd_applicationCombo = new FormData();
    fd_applicationCombo.left = new FormAttachment(0, 10);
    applicationCombo.setLayoutData(fd_applicationCombo);
    formToolkit.adapt(applicationCombo);
    formToolkit.paintBordersFor(applicationCombo);

    return fd_applicationCombo;
}

/**
 * Open the GUI and create the objects to use. Error checking is done to 
 * ensure that a connection was made to the database, and that the queries
 * generated are appropriate for the data desired from the user.
 * @throws IOException 
 */
private void open() throws IOException {
    final Display display = Display.getDefault();
    conn = new DbConnect();

    createShell(display);
    createMenuBar();

    // Create FormData and populate the interface with reqd. elements
    FormData fd_toolCombo     = createApplicationCombo();
    FormData fd_category      = createCategoryCombo();
    FormData fd_issues        = createsubcatCombo();
    FormData fd_script        = createScriptBox();
    FormData fd_btnQuickParts = createQuickPartsBtn(fd_toolCombo);

    // Query the database to get a list of all tools
     ArrayList<String> arrlist = conn.listQuery("tool");

    // Removing below line WILL cause unexpected behavior!
     script.setText(" ");

     // Checks for an error due to connectivity or other.
     if(arrlist.get(0).contains("Error: ")) {
         script.setText(arrlist.get(0));
         subcatCombo.setEnabled(false);
         issueList.setEnabled(false);
         categoryCombo.setEnabled(false);
         applicationCombo.setEnabled(false);
         workInstructions.setEnabled(false);
         script.setEnabled(false);
     }
     else {
         for (String str : arrlist) {
             applicationCombo.add(str); 
         } 
     }

    createListeners();
    createCopyBtn(fd_btnQuickParts, display);
    createLabels(fd_toolCombo, fd_category, fd_issues, fd_script);
    createIssueList();
    createDocLink();

    shlPstmKnowledgeCatalogue.open();
    shlPstmKnowledgeCatalogue.layout();
    while (!shlPstmKnowledgeCatalogue.isDisposed()) {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Create the Hyperlink object that links directly to the EriDoc location
 * that contains the related document. The document is immediately downloaded
 * to the user's computer upon applying valid credentials to the site.
 * The object is only visible if there is an actual link available.
 */
private void createDocLink() {
    FormData fd_list = new FormData();
    fd_list.bottom = new FormAttachment(100, -39);
    fd_list.top = new FormAttachment(subcatCombo, 28);
    fd_list.right = new FormAttachment(applicationCombo, 0, SWT.RIGHT);
    fd_list.left = new FormAttachment(applicationCombo, 0, SWT.LEFT);
    issueList.setLayoutData(fd_list);

    hprlnkDocumentAvailable = formToolkit.createHyperlink(shlPstmKnowledgeCatalogue, "Document Available", SWT.BORDER);
    hprlnkDocumentAvailable.addHyperlinkListener(new IHyperlinkListener() {
        public void linkActivated(HyperlinkEvent arg0) {
            try {
                @SuppressWarnings("unused")
                Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Program Files\\Internet Explorer\\iexplore.exe \"" + hprlnkDocumentAvailable.getHref() + "\"");
            } 
            catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        public void linkEntered(HyperlinkEvent arg0) {
        }
        public void linkExited(HyperlinkEvent arg0) {
        }
    });
    hprlnkDocumentAvailable.setDragDetect(false);
    hprlnkDocumentAvailable.setFont(SWTResourceManager.getFont("Calibri", 9, SWT.NORMAL));
    FormData fd_hprlnkDocumentAvailable = new FormData();
    fd_hprlnkDocumentAvailable.bottom = new FormAttachment(workInstructions, -7);
    fd_hprlnkDocumentAvailable.right = new FormAttachment(100, -10);
    fd_hprlnkDocumentAvailable.left = new FormAttachment(100, -129);
    hprlnkDocumentAvailable.setLayoutData(fd_hprlnkDocumentAvailable);
    formToolkit.paintBordersFor(hprlnkDocumentAvailable);
    hprlnkDocumentAvailable.setVisible(false);
}

/**
 * Create the List object to contain all issues, given the application
 * category, and sub-category. Once a specific issue has been selected
 * the script and work instructions are retreieved from the database and
 * populate their respective objects.
 * 
 * Note: Not all issues will generate both a script and work instruction.
 */
private void createIssueList() {
    Label label = formToolkit.createLabel(shlPstmKnowledgeCatalogue, "Issue", SWT.BORDER);
    label.setForeground(SWTResourceManager.getColor(SWT.COLOR_WHITE));
    label.setFont(SWTResourceManager.getFont("Calibri", 9, SWT.NORMAL));
    label.setBackground(SWTResourceManager.getColor(SWT.COLOR_WIDGET_DARK_SHADOW));
    FormData fd_label = new FormData();
    fd_label.left = new FormAttachment(applicationCombo, 0, SWT.LEFT);
    label.setLayoutData(fd_label);

    ListViewer listViewer = new ListViewer(shlPstmKnowledgeCatalogue, SWT.BORDER | SWT.V_SCROLL);
    issueList = listViewer.getList();
    fd_label.bottom = new FormAttachment(issueList, -6);
    issueList.setCursor(SWTResourceManager.getCursor(SWT.CURSOR_HAND));
    issueList.setToolTipText("Specific problem that the ticket relates to, given the application, category, and sub-category.");
    issueList.setFont(SWTResourceManager.getFont("Calibri", 11, SWT.NORMAL));
    issueList.setBackground(SWTResourceManager.getColor(SWT.COLOR_WHITE));
    issueList.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {

        /*
         * Error checking is done within the list to account for selection
         * that is done outside the index bounds. There is a bug with List
         * objects; indices that have no content are considered to be
         * "out-of-bouds", but are still selectable by the user.
         * 
         * This is handled by catching the "IOOB" exception and using a boolean
         * flag to only populate the script box once a valid selection
         * index has been made.
         */
        @Override
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {

            String selection = "";
            boolean flag = true;
            try {
                selection = issueList.getItem(issueList.getSelectionIndex());
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                flag = false;
            }

            if (flag) {
                conn.getFields().setIssue(selection);
                script.setText("");
                selection = conn.listQuery("script").get(0);
                script.setText(selection);

                if (selection.contains("User")) {
                    int startIndex = selection.indexOf("User,", 0);
                    script.setSelection(startIndex, startIndex + 4);
                    script.showSelection();
                    script.forceFocus();
                }

                hprlnkDocumentAvailable.setVisible(false);
                selection = "";
                selection = conn.listQuery("doc_link").get(0);

                if (!selection.equals("")) {
                    hprlnkDocumentAvailable.setHref(selection);
                    hprlnkDocumentAvailable.setVisible(true);
                }
                workInstructions.setText(" ");
                workInstructions.setText(conn.listQuery("work_instruction").get(0));
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Populates the category combobox with the available categories, after
 * the user selects a tool.
 */
protected void populatecategoryCombo() {
    categoryCombo.removeAll();
    subcatCombo.removeAll();
    script.setText("");
    workInstructions.setText("");
    ArrayList<String> list = conn.listQuery("category"); 

    for (String str : list) {
        categoryCombo.add(str);
    }
}

/**
 * Creates a combobox object to be used for containing list of tools
 * @return combo   Returns the populated combobox that was created
 */
protected Combo populateApplicationCombo () {
    combo_1 = new Combo (shlPstmKnowledgeCatalogue, SWT.READ_ONLY);
    combo_1.setForeground(SWTResourceManager.getColor(SWT.COLOR_BLACK));
    combo_1.setBackground(SWTResourceManager.getColor(SWT.COLOR_WHITE));
    combo_1.setFont(SWTResourceManager.getFont("Calibri", 9, SWT.NORMAL));
        combo_1.setToolTipText("Specifies the tool that the ticket is referencing.");
        return combo_1;
    }
} //End Class
```